# Message: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "ssl://googlemail.com" port 465

Tags: php, codeigniter

> //Does anyone knows how I get this fixed. I have already uncommented necessary files on php.ini but to no avail i still get errors and i am using xampp as my localhost.

```
//emails.php
function email(){
    $this->load->model('user');
    $emails=$this->user->get_emails();
    $this->load->library('email');
    $config['mailtype']='html';
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    foreach($emails as $row){
        $email_config = Array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => 'dirk@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'dirk',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'starttls'  => true,
        'newline'   => "\r\n"
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $email_config);

        if($row['email']){
            $this->email->from('dirk@gmail.com', 'dirk');
            $this->email->to($row['email']);
            $this->email->subject('Test Newsletter');
            $this->email->message('Your email message goes here! <strong>Bold</strong>');
            $this->email->send();
            $this->email->clear();
        }
    }
}
//user.php
function get_emails(){
    $this->db->select('email')->from('users');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();  
}
```

Comment: Very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564400/send-email-by-email-class-in-codeigniter-with-gmail

Comment: @jtheman I have done exactly what they posted but still the same error.

Answer (score 2):

GMail doesn't use `googlemail.com` for smtp, the SMTP server is `smtp.gmail.com` hope that helps.

You need to [set the smtp_host preference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html) to `smtp.gmail.com`.

Comment: so where do i configure my smtp server ?

Answer (score 0):

Put a valid gmail email instead of `abc@gmail.com` at `smtp_user` and fill in the password. Also put a valid email in the `$from`array and `$to` array.

```
  $emailConfig = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'abc@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '*******',
        'mailtype' => 'html', //text or html
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    );
     $from = array('email' => 'abc@gmail.com');
    $to = array('abc@gmail.com');
    $subject = "Testing Mail";
    $message = "Welcome";
    $this->load->library('email', $emailConfig);
    $this->email->initialize($emailConfig);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from($from['email']);
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);

    if ($this->email->send()) {
     echo "success";
          } else {

        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());

    }
}
```